# How do you use Swift 2.0 popFirst() on an Array?

Tags: arrays, swift2

Swift 2.0 `popLast()` works on an Array, like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
let i = arr.popLast()
```

Now `arr` is [1,2] and `i` is 3 (wrapped in an Optional).

But although there is also a `popFirst()`, it doesn't compile. I'm pretty sure it used to, but it doesn't now:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
let i = arr.popFirst() // compile error
```

What's going on here? When is this method actually usable?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Oddly, `popFirst` works only on Array derivatives such as slices. So, for example, this compiles:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
var arrslice = arr[arr.indices]
let i = arrslice.popFirst()
```

Now `arrslice` is [2,3] (as a slice), `i` is 1 (wrapped in an Optional), and `arr` is untouched.

So that's how to use it.

But I do not understand why this odd restriction is imposed on the use of `popFirst()`. I see *how* it is imposed (in the Swift header) but I don't see why.

**EDIT** Thinking about it some more, I'm guessing it has to do with efficiency. When you call `popFirst()` on a slice, you get what amounts to a sparse array: there is now no index 0. So we didn't have to slide all the elements down one slot; instead, we simply incremented the `startIndex`.

Comment: thanks for explaining this mystery!  I guess, you'd just use **removeFirst** - but you have to annoyingly check for the array being empty, with removeFirst.

Comment: @Fattie While removeFirst is another option, it has O(n) time complexity w.r.t O(1) of popFirst.